# Make a part of my email body text bold with using .body instead of .htmlbody in Word VBA

Tags: vba, email, outlook, ms-word

I am trying to bold specific text within the body of my email VBA. In it's current state, I am unable to format any text under `.body`.

However, when I change to `.html body`, I am able to bold text. For example, if I use "< b>JOB NUMBER", the text "JOB NUMBER" is in bold, but the entire body of my email loses all line spaces.

Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks

```
    Private Sub sendemail_Click()


Dim OL              As Object
Dim EmailItem       As Object
Dim Doc             As Document

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Doc = ActiveDocument
Doc.Save

With EmailItem
    .Subject = "QDR" & " " & TextBox22.Value & "_" & TextBox21.Value & "_" &    ComboBox2.Value & "_" & combobox1.Value
    **.Body** = "Attached QDR Request form is for the following: " & vbCrLf & _
    "" & vbCrLf & _
    "JOB NUMBER: " & vbCrLf & _
    TextBox21.Value & vbCrLf & _
    "" & vbCrLf & _
    "QDR NUMBER: " & vbCrLf & _
    TextBox22.Value & vbCrLf & _
    "" & vbCrLf & _
    "CONDITION: " & vbCrLf & _
    combobox1.Value & vbCrLf & _
    "" & vbCrLf & _
    "HARTNESS PART NUMBER: " & vbCrLf & _
    TextBox23.Value & vbCrLf & _
    "" & vbCrLf & _
    "REQUIRED DATE: " & vbCrLf & _
    TextBox31.Value & vbCrLf & _
    "PART REQUIRED SOONER THAN SET LEAD TIME: " & vbCrLf & _
    TextBox30.Value & vbCrLf & _
    "" & vbCrLf & _
    "BRIEF DESCRIPTION OF REQUEST: " & vbCrLf & _
    TextBox25.Value


    .To = "XXXXX@XXXXX.com;"
    .CC = "XXXXX@XXXXX.com;" & "XXXXX@XXXXX.com;"
    .Importance = olImportanceNormal 'Or olImportanceHigh Or olImportanceLow
    .Attachments.Add Doc.FullName
    .Display
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set Doc = Nothing
Set OL = Nothing
Set EmailItem = Nothing


End Sub
```

[image: EXAMPLE PICTURE]

Comment: .body is plain text, and plain text doesn't have formatting. Formatting requires HTML, which is why .htmlbody works.

Comment: You can add line spacing with the html marker: `<br>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can continue to use HTML, simply replace the carriage returns with html's `<br>` for line break. Remember every inline markup (no css) to style html content is valid. So you have free range of fonts, colors, sizes, even web images!

```
msg = "Attached QDR Request form is for the following: <br><br>" _
      & "<b> JOB NUMBER:</b><br>" _
      & TextBox21.Value & "<br><br>" _
      & "<b> QDR NUMBER: </b><br>" _
      & TextBox22.Value & "<br><br>" _
      & "<b> CONDITION: </b><br>" _
      & combobox1.Value & "<br><br>" _
      & "<b> HARTNESS PART NUMBER: <br>" _
      & TextBox23.Value & "<br><br>" _
      & "<b> REQUIRED DATE: </b><br><br>" _
      & "PART REQUIRED SOONER THAN SET LEAD TIME: <br>" _
      & TextBox30.Value & "<br><br>" _
      & "<b>BRIEF DESCRIPTION OF REQUEST: </b><br>" _
      & TextBox25.Value

...
.HTMLBody = msg
```

Alternatively, use an html table for better alignment:

```
msg = "Attached QDR Request form is for the following: <br><br>" _
      & "<table>" _
      & "<tr><td><b> JOB NUMBER: </b></td><td>" & TextBox21.Value & "</td></tr>" _
      & "<tr><td><b> QDR NUMBER: </b></td><td>" & TextBox22.Value & "</td></tr>" _
      & "<tr><td><b> CONDITION: </b></td><td>" & combobox1.Value & "</td></tr>" _
      & "<tr><td><b> HARTNESS PART NUMBER: <b></td><td>" & TextBox23.Value & "</td></tr>" _
      & "<tr><td><b> REQUIRED DATE: </b></td></tr>" _
      & "<tr><td> PART REQUIRED SOONER THAN SET LEAD TIME: </td><td>" & TextBox30.Value & "</td></tr>" _
      & "<tr><td> BRIEF DESCRIPTION OF REQUEST: </td><td>" & TextBox25.Value & "</td></tr>" _
      & "</table>"

...
.HTMLBody = msg
```

Comment: They both worked perfect. I was not too sure on how to work with html. Thanks a lot for your help. Much props

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Thanks, bro.